# Consolidate 2 functions into 1 when having multiple url parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, sharepoint-2013

I am using two functions to open a SharePoint modal dialog, however I see this growing in the future where creating multiple functions for multiple URL's can cause overhead.

I'm not familiar with using "Options". Is there a best practice on how to merge the two functions? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```html
<a href="#" onclick="OpenDashHelpDialog('Dashboard Help Desk Info');"><img src="/PublishingImages/help.png"></a>
<a href="#" onclick="OpenHRHelDeskpDialog('HR Help Desk Info');"><img src="/PublishingImages/help.png" </a>
```

```js
function OpenHelpDeskDialog() {
  var options = {
    url: "/admin/Pages/IThelp.aspx",
    width: 275,
    height: 90,
    dialogReturnValueCallback: DialogCallback
  };
  SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
}

function OpenHRHelpDeskDialog() {
  var options = {
    url: "/admin/Pages/HRDesk.aspx",
    width: 400,
    height: 100,
    dialogReturnValueCallback: DialogCallback
  };
  SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to consolidate the event handlers you need to abstract the logical differences to a higher level. In this case you could use `data` attributes on the `a` elements themselves to store the `width` and `height`, and the `href` attribute to store the URL. Something like this:

```html
<a href="/admin/Pages/IThelp.aspx" class="dialog-trigger" data-width="275" data-height="90">
  <img src="/PublishingImages/help.png" />
</a>
<a href="/admin/Pages/HRDesk.aspx" class="dialog-trigger" data-width="400" data-height="100">
  <img src="/PublishingImages/help.png" />
</a>
```

```js
$('.dialog-trigger').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $a = $(this);

  SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog({
    url: $a.attr('href'),
    width: $a.data('width'),
    height: $a.data('height'),
    dialogReturnValueCallback: DialogCallback
  });
});
```

Note that I created this example in jQuery as that's what was tagged in your question. You could easily achieve the same using plain JS, although I'd strongly advise you use unobtrusive event handlers over the outdated (and ugly) `on*` event attributes.